# Not all Ray CLI dependencies were found

Tags: python, ray

I have installed ray module and I get this warning all the time `FutureWarning: Not all Ray CLI dependencies were found. In Ray 1.4+, the Ray CLI, autoscaler, and dashboard will only be usable via` pip install 'ray[default]'`. Please update your install command. (pid=None)   "update your install command.", FutureWarning)` I updated my pip because of `"update your install command."` but I still get it constantly.

Answer (score 5):

Try `pip install "ray[default]"`! Recently, Ray made its original dependency (`pip install ray`) as a minimal core library that doesn't include autoscaler, dashboard, and metrics dependencies. If you'd like to use all features, you should use `pip install "ray[default]"`.

Comment: thanx but right now I cant tell is your solution working or not because the warning disappeared probably by it's own if I had not done anything without knowing it

Comment: WARNING: ray 1.8.0 does not provide the extra 'default'

Comment: I'm also not using any of that stuff (autoscaler, dashboard, metrics), but still getting the warning/error message.

Answer (score 2):

You should just write `pip install "ray[default]"` . It works.

Comment: And what should be the syntax for requirements.txt ou pyproject.toml?

Comment: WARNING: ray 1.8.0 does not provide the extra 'default'